# nginx files upload streaming with proxy_pass

Tags: file-upload, nginx

I configured nginx as reverse proxy to my node.js application for file uploads with proxy_pass directive.
It works, but my problem is that nginx waits for the whole file body to be uploaded before passing it to the upstream. This causes problems for me, because I want to track upload progress at my application. Any idea how to configure nginx in order to stream file body in real time to the upstream?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is no way to (at least as of now).  Full request will be always buffered before nginx will start sending it to an upstream. To track uploaded files you may try [upload progress](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) module.

Update: in nginx 1.7.11 the [proxy_request_buffering](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_request_buffering) directive is available, which allows to disable buffering of a request body.  It should be used with care though, see docs.

Comment: upload progress module is great, but we're using several servers for uploads processing behind load balancing, so there is always chance that request for progress update will be routed to another server(even with some load balance tricks).

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/768693/nginx-how-to-completely-disable-request-body-buffering In case someone find this useful too.

Answer (score 6):

Tengine (a fork from nginx) support unbuffered upload by setting proxy_request_buffering to off.

http://tengine.taobao.org/document/http_core.html

**Updated:** in nginx 1.7.11 the [proxy_request_buffering](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) directive is available, as [@Maxim Dounin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1597813/maxim-dounin) mentioned above

Comment: Even if proxy_request_buffering is off, the request is still buffered. from the doc: "When you turn off the proxy_request_buffering or fastcgi_request_buffering, Tengine will send the body to backend either it receives more than client_body_postpone_size data or the whole request body has been received."

Answer (score -3):

I suspect that:

```
proxy_buffering off;
```

is what you need, see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering

Comment: I tried that. Unfortunately it seems that this directive works only for response buffering(just as described)

Comment: Here's an nginx ticket for direct proxy streaming of upload data http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/251 hopefully they'll implement it sometime =/