# how to set synchronous transmission under reverse proxy using nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, web.py

I'm using reverse proxy with Nginx. 
When I POST a file to the Nginx, it seems that it will store the whole file in local and forward it to the backend server after received the whole file.
Is there a way to make Nginx receive & forward data  synchronously？

Comment: Don't think you can do that. Also this question is asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282342/nginx-files-upload-streaming-with-proxy-pass

Comment: If it's really important to not transporting files twice, you may try nginx upload module if you have control over your upstream server. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already answered negatively from this SO link: [nginx files upload streaming with proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282342/nginx-files-upload-streaming-with-proxy-pass)

The answer of the above question was from one of the guys who is maintaining nginx code base. So you can forget it for now.

If it's really important to not transporting files twice, you may try nginx upload module if you have control over your upstream server. http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule.

Comment: seems that you're Chinese. May I have your Email or Gtalk to have a talk?

Comment: We can chat on stackoverflow. Not comfortable giving out my email here.

Answer (score 0):

You mean streaming. Yeah, you probably want to play with **proxy_buffering**, **proxy_store** and/or **proxy_temp_file_write_size**:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_store

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_buffering

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_temp_file_write_size

**Side note**: since nginx is single-threaded, then you really want to use that feature (otherwise one upload may block entire server for quite a long time).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I don't think one upload may block entire server for quite a long time since nginx will use epoll and nonblocking I/O to do the I/O multiplexing. Am I right...?

Comment: @Ace I'm not sure to be honest. What your saying sounds reasonable though.