# Nginx Load Balancer buffering

Tags: nginx

Nginx supports proxy *response buffering*, according to [the mailing list](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,244680,244694#msg-244694) (Nov 2013):

> The **proxy_buffering** directive disables response buffering, not request
> buffering.
>
> As of now, there is no way to prevent request body buffering in nginx.
> It's always fully read by nginx before a request is passed to an
> upstream server. It's basically a part of nginx being a web
> accelerator - it handles slow communication with clients by itself and
> only asks a backend to process a request when everything is ready.

Since version 1.7.11 Nginx (Mar 2015) directive **proxy_request_buffering** [see details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282342/nginx-files-upload-streaming-with-proxy-pass/12310121#12...):

> Update: in nginx 1.7.11 the **proxy_request_buffering** directive is
> available, which allows to disable buffering of a request body. It
> should be used with care though, see docs.

See [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering) for more details:

> Syntax: proxy_request_buffering on | off;
>
> Default: proxy_request_buffering on;
>
> Context: http, server, location
>
> When buffering is enabled, the entire request body is read from the
> client before sending the request to a proxied server.
>
> When buffering is disabled, the request body is sent to the proxied
> server immediately as it is received. In this case, the request cannot
> be passed to the next server if nginx already started sending the
> request body.
>
> When HTTP/1.1 chunked transfer encoding is used to send the original
> request body, the request body will be buffered regardless of the
> directive value unless HTTP/1.1 is enabled for proxying.

The question is about buffering for Nginx (Load Balancer). For instance, we have the following scheme:

```
Nginx (LB) -> Nginx (APP) -> Backend
```

Nginx (APP) buffers the request from the load balancer and also buffers response from Backend. But does it make sense to buffer request and response on the Nginx (LB) side if both Nginx nodes are physically located close to each other (less than 2ms ping) with pretty fast network connection in between?

I measured the following benchmarks - Please note that this is for illustration only - Production loads would be significantly higher :

siege --concurrent=50 --reps=50 https://domain.com

proxy_request_buffering on;

```
Transactions:          2500 hits
Availability:        100.00 %
Elapsed time:          58.57 secs
Data transferred:      577.31 MB
Response time:            0.55 secs
Transaction rate:        42.68 trans/sec
Throughput:          9.86 MB/sec
Concurrency:          23.47
Successful transactions:        2500
Failed transactions:            0
Longest transaction:          2.12
Shortest transaction:        0.10
```

proxy_request_buffering off;

```
Transactions:          2500 hits
Availability:        100.00 %
Elapsed time:          57.80 secs
Data transferred:      577.31 MB
Response time:            0.53 secs
Transaction rate:        43.25 trans/sec
Throughput:          9.99 MB/sec
Concurrency:          22.75
Successful transactions:        2500
Failed transactions:            0
Longest transaction:          2.01
Shortest transaction:        0.09
```