# Upload multipart file to tomcat through nginx reverse proxy

Tags: tomcat, nginx

In my current setup:

- SPA application is deployed on nginx server
- REST service is deployed on tomcat server

Please find nginx configuration below:

```
http {

    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    sendfile on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;

    server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        index index.html;
        root html;

        location / {

            try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }

        location /Tomcat {

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tomcat;
            proxy_read_timeout 180;
        }
}
```

Everything works fine except endpoints which are designed to work with upload functionality. Actually when I try to upload some file to nginx following status code `400` is returned from tomcat server with following error message:

```
Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided
```

The same scenario works fine without nginx.

Can someone suggest how it can be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nginx files upload streaming with proxy\_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12282342/nginx-files-upload-streaming-with-proxy-pass)